# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, out-of-memory

I am receiving an outofmemoryerror. I am fetching person info from sqlite db. 
Fetch the whole table with cursor then put into arraylist. Information is name, company, title, address, phone, cell, email and photo (in form of bytes). Here is the code:

```
public class Contacts extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<Stuff> contactsList = null;
private ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter;
private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
private Runnable viewContacts;

// Attributes

private static String name = "";
private static String company = "";
private static String title = "";
private static String address = "";
private static String phone = "";
private static String cel = "";
private static String email = "";
private static byte[] picture = null;
private static int template = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);

    contactsList = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
    contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(this,
            R.layout.contact_list_entry, contactsList);

    setListAdapter(this.contactsAdapter);

    // Setting progress dialog
    viewContacts = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(null, viewContacts, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Contacts.this, "Please wait...",
            "Retrieving data ...", true);

    /*
     * 
     * Log.d("*********", "size :" + Integer.toString(contactsList.size()));
     * 
     * if (contactsList != null && !contactsList.isEmpty()) {
     * 
     * contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); contactsAdapter.clear(); for
     * (int i = 0; i < contactsList.size(); i++) {
     * contactsAdapter.add(contactsList.get(i)); } }
     * 
     * contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     */

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Stuff stuff = contactsList.get(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(Contacts.this, ContactsDetail.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("person", stuff);
    i.putExtra("personBundle", bundle);
    startActivity(i);

}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // Get Data from database

        CardsDatabase info = new CardsDatabase(Contacts.this);
        info.open();
        Cursor c = info.geTContactsData();
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.NAME_R));
            company = c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.COMPANY_R));
            title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.TITLE_R));
            address = c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.ADDRESS_R));
            phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.PHONE_R));
            cel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.CEL_R));
            email = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.EMAIL_R));
            picture = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.PHOTO_R));
            template = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(CardsDatabase.TEMPLATE_R)));
            Stuff s = new Stuff(name, company, title, address, phone, cel,
                    email, template, null, true);
            contactsList.add(s);

            c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();
        info.close();

        if (contactsList != null && contactsList.size() > 0) {
            contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for (int i = 0; i < contactsList.size(); i++)
                contactsAdapter.add(contactsList.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private void getOrders() {
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}

}
```

And this cutom adapter I am using:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stuff> {

private ArrayList<Stuff> contactDataItems;

private Activity context;

public ContactsAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Stuff> contactDataItems) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, contactDataItems);
    this.context = context;
    this.contactDataItems = contactDataItems;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_entry, null);
    }

    Stuff stuff = contactDataItems.get(position);

    if (stuff != null) {

        // name
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        nameTextView.setText(stuff.getName());

        // number
        TextView ratingTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        ratingTextView.setText("Rating: " + stuff.getPhone());

        // thumb image
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_pic);
        final Bitmap bitmap;
        byte[] picture = stuff.getPicture();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        if (picture != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    picture);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Log.d("populate", "stored pic");
        } else {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(),
                    R.drawable.default_pic);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
            picture = bos.toByteArray();
            Log.d("populate", "default pic");

        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    return view;

}
}
```

Logcat is showing these messages:

```
02-27 21:43:42.178: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5713 objects / 551400 bytes in 46ms
02-27 21:43:42.389: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11769 objects / 475280 bytes in 36ms
02-27 21:43:42.436: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 819 objects / 26704 bytes in 36ms
02-27 21:43:42.600: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8720 objects / 349320 bytes in 38ms
02-27 21:43:42.600: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.212MB for 156920-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:42.647: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 104624 bytes in 46ms
02-27 21:43:42.881: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13077 objects / 419024 bytes in 37ms
02-27 21:43:42.881: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.337MB for 235372-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:42.936: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 156928 bytes in 52ms
02-27 21:43:43.210: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16366 objects / 524264 bytes in 38ms
02-27 21:43:43.288: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3251 objects / 104584 bytes in 35ms
02-27 21:43:43.288: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.524MB for 353048-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:43.342: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 235376 bytes in 49ms
02-27 21:43:43.624: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16524 objects / 531352 bytes in 42ms
02-27 21:43:44.092: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 13058 objects / 418136 bytes in 104ms
02-27 21:43:44.092: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.798MB for 529564-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:44.147: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 353056 bytes in 56ms
02-27 21:43:44.452: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16365 objects / 524240 bytes in 44ms
02-27 21:43:44.733: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16366 objects / 524272 bytes in 45ms
02-27 21:43:44.944: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11404 objects / 365480 bytes in 43ms
02-27 21:43:44.944: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.219MB for 794336-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:44.999: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 529568 bytes in 53ms
02-27 21:43:45.280: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16365 objects / 524240 bytes in 47ms
02-27 21:43:45.577: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16367 objects / 524296 bytes in 47ms
02-27 21:43:45.874: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16366 objects / 524272 bytes in 44ms
02-27 21:43:46.155: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16367 objects / 524296 bytes in 47ms
02-27 21:43:46.210: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 738 objects / 24040 bytes in 44ms
02-27 21:43:46.210: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.850MB for 1191496-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:46.272: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 794344 bytes in 56ms
02-27 21:43:46.592: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16365 objects / 524240 bytes in 81ms
02-27 21:43:46.913: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16376 objects / 524288 bytes in 51ms
02-27 21:43:47.217: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16376 objects / 524288 bytes in 51ms
02-27 21:43:47.546: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16366 objects / 524280 bytes in 53ms
02-27 21:43:47.850: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16376 objects / 524288 bytes in 51ms
02-27 21:43:48.131: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16376 objects / 524288 bytes in 48ms
02-27 21:43:48.194: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1069 objects / 34464 bytes in 46ms
02-27 21:43:48.202: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.797MB for 1787236-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:48.288: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 1191504 bytes in 91ms
02-27 21:43:48.647: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20800 objects / 665856 bytes in 56ms
02-27 21:43:49.006: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20832 objects / 666880 bytes in 60ms
02-27 21:43:49.366: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20832 objects / 666880 bytes in 57ms
02-27 21:43:49.733: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20822 objects / 666856 bytes in 64ms
02-27 21:43:50.077: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20822 objects / 666864 bytes in 56ms
02-27 21:43:50.413: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20832 objects / 666880 bytes in 56ms
02-27 21:43:50.756: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 20832 objects / 666880 bytes in 56ms
02-27 21:43:50.850: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3179 objects / 101984 bytes in 54ms
02-27 21:43:50.905: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.217MB for 2680844-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:50.983: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 1787240 bytes in 82ms
02-27 21:43:51.467: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30122 objects / 964160 bytes in 73ms
02-27 21:43:52.296: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30122 objects / 964160 bytes in 64ms
02-27 21:43:52.764: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30124 objects / 964224 bytes in 65ms
02-27 21:43:53.264: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30124 objects / 964224 bytes in 66ms
02-27 21:43:53.764: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30115 objects / 964240 bytes in 67ms
02-27 21:43:54.241: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30124 objects / 964224 bytes in 67ms
02-27 21:43:54.717: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 30124 objects / 964224 bytes in 68ms
02-27 21:43:54.952: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12565 objects / 402336 bytes in 65ms
02-27 21:43:54.952: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.348MB for 4021256-byte allocation
02-27 21:43:55.030: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 2680848 bytes in 79ms
02-27 21:43:55.710: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 79ms
02-27 21:43:56.381: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 79ms
02-27 21:43:57.100: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 81ms
02-27 21:43:57.788: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 82ms
02-27 21:43:58.491: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 83ms
02-27 21:43:59.186: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 84ms
02-27 21:43:59.874: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 44067 objects / 1410704 bytes in 85ms
02-27 21:44:00.405: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 26650 objects / 853360 bytes in 81ms
02-27 21:44:00.413: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.543MB for 6031876-byte allocation
02-27 21:44:00.506: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 4021264 bytes in 96ms
02-27 21:44:01.491: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65011 objects / 2080912 bytes in 105ms
02-27 21:44:02.694: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65021 objects / 2080928 bytes in 107ms
02-27 21:44:03.741: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65011 objects / 2080912 bytes in 110ms
02-27 21:44:04.780: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65021 objects / 2080928 bytes in 110ms
02-27 21:44:05.827: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65011 objects / 2080912 bytes in 114ms
02-27 21:44:06.858: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65021 objects / 2080928 bytes in 111ms
02-27 21:44:07.913: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65011 objects / 2080912 bytes in 117ms
02-27 21:44:08.702: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 47564 objects / 1522304 bytes in 114ms
02-27 21:44:08.991: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.337MB for 9047804-byte allocation
02-27 21:44:09.225: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 6031880 bytes in 235ms
02-27 21:44:10.303: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65527 objects / 2097120 bytes in 137ms
02-27 21:44:11.374: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 143ms
02-27 21:44:12.530: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 132ms
02-27 21:44:13.553: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 133ms
02-27 21:44:14.577: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65518 objects / 2097136 bytes in 135ms
02-27 21:44:15.608: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 139ms
02-27 21:44:16.655: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 139ms
02-27 21:44:17.983: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65522 objects / 2096960 bytes in 141ms
02-27 21:44:19.014: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 147ms
02-27 21:44:20.038: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65518 objects / 2097136 bytes in 144ms
02-27 21:44:21.069: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 65528 objects / 2097152 bytes in 150ms
02-27 21:44:21.655: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 33225 objects / 1063456 bytes in 139ms
02-27 21:44:21.655: I/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 13571696-byte allocation
02-27 21:44:21.788: D/dalvikvm(21573): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 133ms
02-27 21:44:21.788: E/dalvikvm-heap(21573): Out of memory on a 13571696-byte allocation.
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40020990 self=0xce28
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   | sysTid=21573 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345017736
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   | schedstat=( 36479370361 3853179681 6072 )
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:~123)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at com.colony.businesscard.Contacts$1.run(Contacts.java:129)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4732)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-27 21:44:21.788: I/dalvikvm(21573):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 21:44:21.796: D/AndroidRuntime(21573): Shutting down VM
02-27 21:44:21.796: W/dalvikvm(21573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400208b0)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:123)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at com.colony.businesscard.Contacts$1.run(Contacts.java:129)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4732)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-27 21:44:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(21573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 21:44:21.881: I/Process(21573): Sending signal. PID: 21573 SIG: 9
```

Can I anyone tel me where the problem is?

Comment: Looks like the bitmap is causing this OOM exception. Search for it and you will get the answer.

Comment: each row has image , i am fetching whole table.

Comment: Well, the answer is that you consume too much memory. Use less. Only load what you currently need (e.g. only what is displayed + some more for scrolling) and free old + load new data when you need new data. Loading everything at once isn't a great approach on a limited mobile device. *(You can already see how much the gc has to work before the exception)*

Comment: How is that possible with sqlite !! i have to query for whole table once . What approach should i use ?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to store the actual picture in database ? Couldn't you just store the path to the file in the DB and the picture in internal storage ?

Comment: Please update your self, use recyclerview, glide, picasso all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to save only image path into SQLite DB and not the byte array. You can save image into local directory and then you can store path into DB. I hope help you.